# ngx-translate with dynamic text on ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ngx-translate

I'm using [**ngx-translate**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/) for internationalization on `Ionic 3` app. I have used `pipe` nicely on `HTML` code. But now I have a situation like below on `ts` file. Can you tell me how to handle such dynamic use case with `ngx`?

```
 updateApi(topic) {
     this.showToast(`Topic ${topic.name} subscribed!`);//this is the dynamic text
  }

 showToast(message) {
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: message,
            duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
    }
```

The problem here is I don't know the value of `${topic.name}` up front. So how can I give the `key/value` for that on `i18n` `json` file? or am I missing something here?

Comment: The URL doesn't work anymore: use https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/ng2-translate/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to inject the Translate Service in your component :

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
```

And declare in your translation file something like this :

```
{
  "TOPIC": "Topic {{value}} subscribed!"
}
```

Then you can choose one of the following way :

**Translate instantly :**

```
showToast(this.translate.instant('TOPIC', {value: topic.name}));
```

**Translate with an observable**

```
this.translate.get('TOPIC', {value: topic.name}).subscribe(res => {
      showToast(res);
});
```

**Translate directly in the template**

```
{{ 'TOPIC' | translate: {value: topic.name} }}
```

Comment: The problem here is I don't know the value of `${topic.name}` up front. So how can I give the `key/value` for that on `i18n` `json` file? or am I missing something here?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your question. Hope it helps.

Comment: but when language changes still default language message is coming.

Answer (score 5):

You also can do it by this way:

```
this.showToast(this.translate.instant('TOPIC', {value: ${topic.name}}));
```

Comment: but when language changes still default language message is coming.