# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'moreText' of undefined using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate for managing the translation functionality for an angular application having ng-version="4.4.7"

I have the following key in translations file:

```
en.json :
{
  "moreText": "more"
}

es.json :
{
  "moreText": "más"
}
```

TestService.ts:

```
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  public moreText: string;
  constructor(private zone: NgZone, public translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.moreText = translateService.instant("moreText");
  }

}
```

I am trying to use the moreText in test.model.ts file

test.model.ts:

```
import { TestService } from "./test.service";
export class TestModel {
  constructor(data: any, private testService?: TestService) {
  }

get parsedCountries(): string {
    const countriesAmount = this.countries.length;

    return (countriesAmount < 4
      ? this.countries
      : this.countries
          .slice(0, 2)
          .concat(`${countriesAmount - 2} ${this.testService.moreText}`)
    ).join(", ");
  }
}
```

I don't see any compile time errors, but at rumtime when it comes to use moreText in the parsedCountries() I am getting an error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'moreText' of undefined using ngx-translate

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Here I am trying to read the key:moreText from the translation file based on the language in the TestModel class. The value of moreText is calculated in the TestService class where the TranslateService instance is injected.

Comment: Thank you, I can read. But we need a [mcve] to know how you declared your classes, if they're injected into the right module, if you have overriden them in your providers list, or anything that could be your fault. Besides, by providing a [mcve], you usually find your error yourself.

Comment: I tried to follow the example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155989/ngx-translate-with-dynamic-text-on-ts-file

Comment: Okay I give up. Good luck with your issue.

Comment: I have created a project with all the details: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vlspz  . Here I am trying to use the value of MoreText from the moreTextContent() method of test.model.ts file. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185432/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-patro-and-trichetriche).