# multi language web application in angular and laraval

Tags: angular, laravel

I am creating a project using angular for frontend and laraval for rest apis..In my application i have feature to change the web page to some other language. I know there is module `ngx-translation` which is for angular to convert web pages.but i don't know how to convert the user data which is coming from server..

I have implemented ngx-translation to covert the web pages but i have problem while converting server data like user info..

Can someone please suggest what is best idea to make multi language web application or there is any tool which can convert the web pages to some other language

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic server side data, you can make an api to get key/value and save them in client side. then you must pass them to ngx-translate.

this is an accepted answer for your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260563/4751073